# Violent Python, The cuckoo's egg -- Returning me to root terminal

Tags: python, cryptography, salt, crypt

I've started learning `violent python` and one of the exercises in the book is to write a basic `UNIX password cracker using crypt()`.
The password they want to crack is `egg` and the salt is `HX`
Unfortunately for me, for some reason the terminal runs the `Crypt.py` correctly, doesn't come up with any errors and then returns back to `/root`.

```
import crypt
def testPass(cryptPass):
    salt = cryptPass[0:2]
    dictFile = open('common.txt', 'r')
    for word in dictFile.readlines():
        word = word.strip('\n')
        cryptWord = crypt.crypt(word,salt)
        if (cryptWord == cryptPass):
            print "[+] Found Password: "+word+"\n"
            return
    print "[-] Password Not Found.\n"
def main():
    passFile = open('passwords.txt')
    for line in passFile.readlines():
        if ":" in line:
            user = line.split(':')[0]
            cryptPass = line.split(':')[1].strip(' ')
            print "[*] Cracking Password For: "+user
            testPass(cryptPass)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Assuming I am not totally off, I have a `passwords.txt file` with the password `egg` and a common.txt (which is a dictionary). Clearly I've made some mistake somewhere.

Comment: Check if your condition is met. Is there a `:` in the file?

Comment: I figured out what was wrong, thanks everyone who looked. My password.txt file was missing the hashed password. 

Ended up leaving me with a code that compared HX9LLTdc/jiDE to egg